Receive push notification when app in foreground after disable notification permission in settings
Although I disable notification permission in setting, still receive push notification when app in foreground
AppDelegate::application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)[L:------------------didReceiveRemoteNotification [AnyHashable("aps"): { alert = { body = "Push payload body"; subtitle = "Test push notification"; title = "Push Hero"; }; }]------------------]

Your app needs permission to display notifications. It doesn't need permission to register for push notifications or receive push notifications while running. In your didReceiveRemoteNotification code you are calling a function to display the notification in your app. You can check the notification permissions and not call that function if you don't have permission, if that is wha you want to do

When the notification permissions are disabled, the system won't show notifications in the notification center or as banners. However, if the app is running in the foreground, the application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) method can still be called. This happens because the notification payload is delivered directly to the app when it is active.

Can you have any document or link apple talk about this. Thank you verymuch

See this note that you can register without getting notification permission. The permission is only required if you want the system to display your notifications when your app isn't on screen
